# Jquery, delete an article and pull in the first one from next page

Tags: jquery, pagination, article

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery, delete an article and pull in the first one from next page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244680/jquery-delete-an-article-and-pull-in-the-first-one-from-next-page)

Hi i'm trying to build a blog with a pagination system (ex. 5 articles per page).
Everything is fine with the pagination itself but next to each article i included a "delete" button allowing the admin to remove dynamically (jquery)the related article and its content.
What I want now is to "append"(without refreshing) the first article of the next page when I delete an article, the second when I delete another article,then the third and so on..
I want this to avoid to have a blank page if i keep on deleting articles without refreshing.

I'm actually using php and a mysql database to store data
for paginating i'm using something similar to this
[link](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/09/pagination-with-jquery-mysql-and-php.html)

thanks
luca